# DMCA service on Bing search engine

Tags: search-engines

Does Bing offer a similar service to the one Google search engine offers below?

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/dmca-notice?hl=en

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, though there are separate processes for reporting [infringement in search results](http://www.microsoft.com/info/FormForSearch.aspx) vs. [in advertising](http://advertise.bingads.microsoft.com/en-us/intellectual-property)